# verantwortungsvoll vs. verantwortungsbewusst vs. verantwortlich

Tags: difference

Please what is the difference between those three words??? They are all translated to "responsible". If you could provide me with examples for each one it would really help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don‘t use just one possible translation for each word. A good dictionary will give you more than one and example sentences... this site is not here to replace dictionaries...sorry.

Comment: Please consider example sentences where you found these words and where you struggle to grasp the difference. E.g. what you understood/how you would translate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is difficult to explain in english; but let me try.

Even though *verantwortungsvoll*, *verantwortungsbewusst*, and *verantwortlich* share the denotation *responsible* / *responsibly*, the connotations are different. Despite this, *verantwortungsvoll* and *verantwortungsbewusst* are often used interchangably in every-day language. But someone who writes in a higher register should know the nuances.

#### Verantwortungsvoll

This just means *associated with responsibility*. Its literal meaning is *with full responsibility*.

> Anne geht verantwortungsvoll mit den Daten um.
>   
>   → Anne handles the data with full responsibility.

Note that this does not necessarily imply that Anne is aware of her behavior. She might unsconsciously act in a right (responsible) manner.

#### Verantwortungsbewusst

This literally means *aware of one's responsibility*.

> Anne ist eine verantwortungsbewusste Mitarbeiterin.
>   
>   → Anne is an employee who is aware of her responsibility.

Note that *verantwortungsbewusst sein* (being aware of one's own responsibility) is not the same as *sich der Verantwortung bewusst sein* (being aware that one is responsible / accountable). While the first requires that the person *is* actually behaving responsibly, the second does not require this. For example:

> Der Busfahrer war verantwortungsbewusst.

versus

> Der Busfahrer war sich seiner Verantwortung bewusst. Er fuhr aber trotzdem immer zu schnell.

#### Verantwortlich

This means that somebody is *accountable* or *in charge* of something. It is not a good substitute for the other two words and vice versa.

> Er fühlte sich verantwortlich.
>   
>   → He felt accountable.
>
> Sie sind für unsere Sicherheit verantwortlich.
>   
>   → They are in charge of our security.

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks a lot!!